# How to webscraping for multiple pages in website using python and beautifulsoup4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Iam trying to scraping Traveloka.com website and success to get data of reviews customer. But, the problem is just in 1 page. I need to get all data of reviews customer on (page 1,2,3.... and more). Iam using beautifulsoup4. I tried to modification the code and see the tutorial, but still not working. Please help me guys. And this is my code on below.

## **Import**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
```

### URL Link

```
my_url = 'https://www.traveloka.com/id-id/hotel/indonesia/horison-ultima-bandung-2000000081026?spec=26-05-2019.27-05-2019.1.1.HOTEL.2000000081026.Horison%20Ultima%20Bandung.2&prevSearchId=1634474608622074440&loginPromo=1&contexts=%7B%7D'
```

### HTML Parsing

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
```

### Grab each reviews customer

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"_2K0Zb _278Mz"})  #div reviews
```

### Looping

for container in containers:

```
username_container = container.findAll("div",{"class":"css-76zvg2 r-1inkyih r-b88u0q"}) # review (username)
username = username_container[0].text

tanggal_container = container.findAll("div",{"class":"css-76zvg2 r-1ud240a r-1b43r93 r-b88u0q r-1d4mawv r-tsynxw"}) # review (tanggal)
tanggal = tanggal_container[0].text

deskripsi_container = container.findAll("div",{"class":"css-1dbjc4n r-1wzrnnt"}) # review (deskripsi)
deskripsi = deskripsi_container[0].text

print("username : " + username)
print("tanggal : " + tanggal)
print("deskripsi : " + deskripsi)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow @Jakarius ! Have a look on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and what is a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will even have rewards at visiting those pages. We will not write code for you. Share what you have tried so far and we will try to improve it.

Comment: please look into this beautiful framework : https://scrapy.org/